# ReportViewer DatePicker and HttpHandler Issue in Chrome

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-chrome, reportviewer

I have a problem with ReportViewer in my project. In Chrome, datepickers were not show up for SSRS datetime parameters. I've found [that](http://www.rajbandi.net/fixing-ssrs-report-viewer-control-date-picker-in-google-chrome) solution, it worked but this time when I click on "Next Page" or "Last Page" icon of report viewer, results are disapearing. I checked the console and I found that error in response:

> The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file.  Add <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /> to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, or add <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /> to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.

**My HTML Code:**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
   <Scripts>
      <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Kitap/js/ReportViewer.js" />
      <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Kitap/js/datepicker-tr.js" />
   </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="MyReportViewer" runat="server"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
<asp:HiddenField ID="DatePickers" runat="server" />
```

**ReportViewer.js File:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
fixParameters();
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(applicationInitHandler);

function applicationInitHandler() {
    fixParameters();
}

function fixParameters() {
    var exists = false;
    var items = $('.ui-datepicker-trigger');
    if (items != null && items.length > 0) {
        exists = true;
    }

    if (isChrome && !exists) {

        // add date picker
        $($(":hidden[id*='DatePickers']").val().split(",")).each(function (i, item) {
            var h = $("table[id*='ParametersGrid'] span").filter(function (i) {
                var v = "[" + $(this).text() + "]";
                return (v != null && item != "" && v.indexOf(item) >= 0);
            }).parent("td").next("td").find("input").datepicker({
                showOn: "button"
               , buttonImage: '/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.calendar.gif'
               , buttonImageOnly: true
               //, dateFormat: 'mm.dd.yy'
               , changeMonth: true
               , changeYear: true
            });
        });

        // remove time from date
        $($(":hidden[id*='DatePickers']").val().split(",")).each(function (i, item) {
            var h = $("table[id*='ParametersGrid'] span").filter(function (i) {
                var v = "[" + $(this).text() + "]";
                return (v != null && item != "" && v.indexOf(item) >= 0);
            }).parent("td").next("td").find("input").parent().children("input").each(function () {
                $(this).val($(this).val().substring($(this).val().length - 12, 0));
            });
        });
    }
}});
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string personParam = ""; //Person Type, I'm setting this in a switch-case but didn't write here.
    MyReportViewer.AsyncRendering = false;
    MyReportViewer.Width = new Unit(100, UnitType.Percentage);
    MyReportViewer.Height = 600;
    MyReportViewer.ShowExportControls = true;
    MyReportViewer.ShowPrintButton = true;

    MyReportViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
    MyReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(@"http://1.1.1.1/ReportServer");

    MyReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new MyReportServerCredentials();
    MyReportViewer.ShowPrintButton = true;

    ReportParameter prmPerson = new ReportParameter(personParam, activePerson.Id.ToString());
    MyReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(prmPerson );

    MyReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/YAYINCILIK/Ekitap/Rapor";

}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create a Web service proxy object and set credentials
    ReportingService2010 rs = new ReportingService2010();
    rs.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

}

[Serializable]
public sealed class MyReportServerCredentials :
    IReportServerCredentials
{
    public System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
    {
        get
        {
            // Use the default Windows user.  Credentials will be
            // provided by the NetworkCredentials property.
            return null;
        }
    }

    public System.Net.ICredentials NetworkCredentials
    {
        get
        {
            // User name
            string userName = "username";

            // Password
            string password = "password";

            // Domain
            string domain = "domain";

            return new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
        }
    }

    public bool GetFormsCredentials(out System.Net.Cookie authCookie,
                out string userName, out string password,
                out string authority)
    {
        authCookie = null;
        userName = null;
        password = null;
        authority = null;

        // Not using form credentials
        return false;
    }
}
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);

    DatePickers.Value = GetDateParameters();
}
private string GetDateParameters()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;

    foreach (ReportParameterInfo info in MyReportViewer.ServerReport.GetParameters())
    {
        if (info.DataType == ParameterDataType.DateTime)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                sb.Append(string.Format(",[{0}]", info.Prompt));
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(string.Format("[{0}]", info.Prompt));
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you followed the suggestion from response?

Comment: Yes but nothing has changed. @JesseJames

Comment: @emrea - Can you please post you're ReportViewer Page code and code behind please.